# Show that for any number x, there is a positive integer n such that n is greater than x

Tags: real-analysis

I have seen a couple of proofs for this on this site but I couldn't understand them.  This has to be solved using the Archimedean Property but unfortunately I can't seem to make any sense out of the different forms that are on the net. 
Also pls recommend some material which I can use for real analysis.

Comment: It would probably help if you could explain a little more - and give an example of the type of proof you can't understand. For example, are you working with $x$ being a Real Number? In which case you can use the properties of the Real Numbers in the proof - but there are alternative equivalent definitions of the Reals, and it might be important to know which you are using.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264859/why-n-frac1-epsilon, in two of the answers given they have stated "Archimedean property of R; from what you’ve written it sounds like you’re working with the version that says that for any real number x there is a positive integer n such that n>x". However they didn't mention the x in the ans. I'm assuming that x = 1/epsilon. Also for the Archimedean Property, there are the two forms nx>y and 1/epsilon < n